Jenkins 2.491: WARNING 'Jenkins.agentProtocols no longer configurable' despite removing it from JCasC
Issue
I'm getting a warning on every start of Jenkins about this (since upgrade to 2.486)
jenkins-master [id=21] WARNING jenkins.model.Jenkins#setAgentProtocols               jenkins-master 2:00 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Jenkins.agentProtocols no longer configurable
From what I understand, support for configuring agentProtocols was deprecated starting from Jenkins 2.486. That is when I removed it from configuration.
All plugins are up to date.

Question
Where could Jenkins still be getting this agentProtocols from, if it's nowhere in casc or config.xml files?
